# PHP exec command has the result 0 even if an error occurs

Tags: ssh, php, exit, exec

I have this PHP code:

```
$execout=exec('ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx "sudo /etc/init.d/smokeping reload"',$output1,$result);
if($result !=0){
    echo"that can't reload";
}
else{
    echo "successfully reloaded";
}
```

in this code, always gives the `$result = 0`. Why is that? Sometimes if smokeping has an error, it shows that error when bellow command typed in command line,

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx "sudo /etc/init.d/smokeping reload"
```

then it gives this error messege.

```
* Reloading latency logger daemon configuration...
ERROR: can't open /etc/smokeping/devices/errorfilename: No such file or   directory
 ...done.
```

so it has an error, but `$result` every times gives the same as 0 . (Whether it had an error or not)

Why does the exec command behaves like this(in php and CLI)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a little answer for that.for the above code I put `2>&1` at the end. As

```
$execout=exec('ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx "sudo /etc/init.d/smokeping reload 2>&1"',$output1,$result);
```

When there is an error occurs in the application that I'm going to reload(smokeping), `print_r($output);` gives the error as

```
Array ( [0] => * Reloading latency logger daemon configuration... [1] => ERROR: can't open /etc/smokeping/devices/errorfilename: No such file or directory [2] => ...done. )
```

Now I can handle it from here.Thank you all .

Answer (score 2):

In

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx "sudo /etc/init.d/smokeping reload"
```

Your shell

(1) (or in your example the shell started by PHP's `exec()`) will parse that command line and if found execute a `ssh`

(2) Command which will contact a `sshd`

(3) Server on `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx` which after successful authentication will call a `shell`

(4) Which will interpret that `sudo` command line and run the `sudo`

(5) Command which after checking permissions will run `/etc/init.d/smokeping`

(6) Which itself is probably a shell script that runs several commands.

Several things may fail there. If all the steps one to 5 are successful, then the exit status of `/etc/init.d/smokeping` will be reported to your shell because `sudo` does report the exit status of the command it runs and the remote shell exits with the exit status of the last command it ran and `ssh` reports the exit status of the remote shell.

Now, commands return a non-zero exit status, by convention, to report to the caller that they've not managed to do what they were asked to do.

In your case, either `/etc/init.d/smokeping` decided that whatever error occurred was not enough to warrant a non-zero exit status, or that script is not written correctly and fails to return with a non-zero exit status upon failure (or some pathological case involving misbehaviour or misconfiguration of `ssh`, `sudo` or the remote shell).

`/etc/init.d` scripts are often written with `set -e`. With that flag enabled, the shell interpreting the script will by default exit when a command it runs fails (with the non-zero exit status of the failing command), which makes me think here we may be in the first situation: "smokeping" does decide to report that it has successfully reloaded.

An example of a pathological case could be for instance: `bash` used as the remote shell (`bash` does read the `~/.bashrc` when invoked over `ssh` even though those are not interactive shells), and the `~/.bashrc` has something like:

```
trap 'whatever...; exit 0' EXIT
```

Which would cause the exit status of interactive shells or shells started over `ssh` or `rsh` to always be `0`.

Comment: In OPs case, wouldn't successful execution of `ssh` return 0 regardless of what happens on the remote end?

Comment: @MelBoyce, that would only happen in pathological cases, `ssh` is meant to return the exit status of the remote shell.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas-Thank you very much.And you explain that very clear.